# How to notify in Google Chrome using window.Notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I'm trying to display desktop notifications using the window.Notification object, but I could not do it.

This is my code:

```
var noti = new Notification("Bob: Hi", { tag: 'chat_Bob' });
noti.show();
```

That works on Firefox, even without the `noti.show()` statement, but not in Google Chrome.
It doesn't work even after user grants permissions.

Comment: Maybe reading the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_Web_Notifications) helps.

Comment: This documentation is from Mozilla, I have no problems with Firefox.

Comment: I know. The documentation is cross-browser.